# How to set wlp.password.encryption.key value in Liberty Profile

Tags: encryption, websphere-liberty

We are trying to encrypt sensitive information stored in server.xml of Liberty Profile. To do that we are using `securityUtility` tool with "aes" encoding type. Understand from the IBM infocenter that a custom key value can be set with the property `wlp.password.encryption.key` for the encryption. If this value is not set the tool will use default value.
We want to set up a custom value for the `wlp.password.encryption.key` property, so that it can be used during the encryption.

However I could not find any details how can we set this property.  What are the syntax to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some information how to use encryption key - [Liberty profile: The limits to protection through password encryption](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_pwd_encrypt.html)

> The encryption key used for decrypting can be overridden from the default by setting the `wlp.password.encryption.key` property. This
>   property should not be set in the `server.xml` file that stores the
>   password, but in a separate configuration file that is included by the
>   `server.xml` file. This separate configuration file should contain only
>   a single property declaration, and should be stored outside the normal
>   configuration directory for the server. This ensures that the file
>   containing the key is not included when you are running the server
>   dump or package command.
>   The encryption key property can also be specified as a bootstrap property.

How to define property (in server.xml or in separate file):

```
<server>
  ...
  <variable name="wlp.password.encryption.key" value="yourKey" />
</server>
```

How to include separate file in server.xml:

```
<server>
  ...
  <include location="${shared.config.dir}/key.xml" />
</server>
```

`bootstrap.properties` is optional file, it does not exist by default. You must create it in the same directory where server.xml is stored, by default `usr/servers/server_name`.
Define entry in there like this:

```
wlp.password.encryption.key = yourKey
```